# search through array and find 1 couple optimally?

Tags: php, arrays

Let`s suppose we have a simple (non-assoc) array with 100001 values and these values set in unsorted order like 45, 12, 32, 23. We know that in this array is 1 couple of numbers, how to find it optimally - not via 2 foreach loops and even not via 2 for loops with 100001/2 division?

Comment: So numbers from 1 to 100000 and one duplicate or what? Or what is a *couple of numbers*?

Comment: yes 1 dublicate, sorry I`m just Russian - bad Engl at all =) Like I said I solved this task by 2 methods the one is to make 2 loops through array and compare one by one and the other is do divide on 2 and loop 1-st from start/begining and the second from the end to bigining/actually half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
$result=array_count_values($arr);
$value=array_search(2, $result);

print $value;
```

Comment: man, relax. 1) this code will find any pairs of any digits, "2" means "pair". read manual. 2) php-functions will always work faster, than your code. If it's your homework and theoretic question - ask it on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is not sorted, the ONLY search method other than random scatteryshot is to scan the array sequentially and look for your two numbers:

```
$first_key = null;
$second_key = null;

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == $first_number) {
       $first_key = $key;
    }
    if ($val == $second_number) {
       $second_key = $key;
    }
    if (!is_null($first_key) && !is_null($second_key)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Once both numbers are found, or you reach the end of the array, the loop will exit.

Comment: May be U meant this `foreach ($arr AS $val1) {
  foreach ($arr AS $val2) {
    if ($val1===$val2) return $val1;
  }
}`nope, like I said this is suboptimal and I know this and wrote about it already. Just read cearefully guys.

Comment: I did read carefully. You posted a snippet of some comma separated numbers, and say you want to find a "couple numbers". Perhaps you should say if it's a multi-dimensional array, or better yet, post a chunk of var_dump/print_r output to demonstrated what it really looks like.

Comment: Yes? And? `$array[0] = 1; $array[100001] = 42`. There you go, 100,001 array elements. My eyes are fine, you need to work on your question asking abilities.